# Como hacer un contador en Javascript en función de un botón al dar click

Tags: javascript, html, botón, eventos, contador

Estoy practicando haciendo un pequeño juego con inputs y botones, en el cuál el primer input yo agrego un número y en el segundo input si añado ese numero repetido da como resultado un mensaje "Adivinaste" y se tendría que sumar 1 punto, luego si adivino otro numero en el input tendría que sumarse otro punto en el cual ya llevaría 2 puntos, pero se me queda en el mismo punto, no entiendo como hago para que el contador funcione correctamente acumulando puntos cada vez que yo "adivine el numero" ingresado en el primer input.

```js
var num_uno = document.getElementById('numuno');
var num_dos = document.getElementById('numdos');
const botonAgregar = document.getElementById('boton');
const botonAdivinar = document.getElementById('botondos');
const mostrarResultado = document.getElementById('resultado');
var cantidadPuntos = document.getElementById('puntos');


botonAgregar.addEventListener('click',()=> {
   numeroAdivinar = num_uno.value;
   numeroAdivinar.innerHTML;
   console.log(numeroAdivinar);
   num_uno.value = "";
});
botonAdivinar.addEventListener('click',() => {
    let i;
    let contador = 0;
    numeroParaAdivinar = num_dos.value;
    numeroParaAdivinar.innerHTML;
    if (numeroParaAdivinar == numeroAdivinar) {
        mostrarResultado.innerHTML = `${"Adivinaste"}`
        cantidadPuntos.innerHTML = `${contador++}`;
        
    } else {
        mostrarResultado.innerHTML = `${"Erraste"}`
    }
});
```

```css
.container {
   margin: auto;
   width: 50%;
   border: 3px solid green;
   padding: 10px;
}

.numuno {
    text-align: center;
    
}
.numdos {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.resultado {
   
    border: 3px solid red;
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    
}

.boton {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

span {
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    
    width: 50px;
    
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Aplicando</title>
  </head>

  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="index.html">Inicio</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="juego.html">Juego</a>
    </li>

  </ul>


  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="numuno">
            <input type="text" id="numuno">
        </div>
        <div class="boton">
          <button id="boton">Agregar</button>
      </div>
        <div class="numdos">
            <input type="text" id="numdos">
        </div>
        <div class="boton">
            <button id="botondos">Adivinar</button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span id="resultado"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="">Puntos</label>
      <span id="puntos"></span>
    </div>
    
    
        

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!--MIS SCRIPTS-->
    <script src="juego.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

En este caso si te fijas bien `let contador = 0;` se ejecuta cada vez que que haces un click en el botón lo que ocasiona que siempre se iguale a cero, la variable contador debe estar fuera del evento.

De esta forma:

```js
var num_uno = document.getElementById('numuno');
var num_dos = document.getElementById('numdos');
const botonAgregar = document.getElementById('boton');
const botonAdivinar = document.getElementById('botondos');
const mostrarResultado = document.getElementById('resultado');
var cantidadPuntos = document.getElementById('puntos');
let contador = 0; // Deberia ir aquí


botonAgregar.addEventListener('click',()=> {
   numeroAdivinar = num_uno.value;
   numeroAdivinar.innerHTML;
   console.log(numeroAdivinar);
   num_uno.value = "";
});
botonAdivinar.addEventListener('click',() => {
    let i;
    numeroParaAdivinar = num_dos.value;
    numeroParaAdivinar.innerHTML;
    if (numeroParaAdivinar == numeroAdivinar) {
        mostrarResultado.innerHTML = `${"Adivinaste"}`
        cantidadPuntos.innerHTML = `${++contador}`; // Cambiamos de contador++ a ++contador
        
    } else {
        mostrarResultado.innerHTML = `${"Erraste"}`
    }
});
```

```css
.container {
   margin: auto;
   width: 50%;
   border: 3px solid green;
   padding: 10px;
}

.numuno {
    text-align: center;
    
}
.numdos {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.resultado {
   
    border: 3px solid red;
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    
}

.boton {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

span {
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    
    width: 50px;
    
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Aplicando</title>
  </head>

  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="index.html">Inicio</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="juego.html">Juego</a>
    </li>

  </ul>


  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="numuno">
            <input type="text" id="numuno">
        </div>
        <div class="boton">
          <button id="boton">Agregar</button>
      </div>
        <div class="numdos">
            <input type="text" id="numdos">
        </div>
        <div class="boton">
            <button id="botondos">Adivinar</button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span id="resultado"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="">Puntos</label>
      <span id="puntos"></span>
    </div>
    
    
        

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!--MIS SCRIPTS-->
    <script src="juego.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Ahh y solo una cosa mas, en tu caso no seria `contador++` sino `++contador` para que la suma no sea después de mostrar el puntaje.

Saludos ;)